# How can i authorize my PC to my phone that doesn't work properly?

Tags: adb, launcher, samsung-galaxy-note-4, screen-resolution, authorization

So yesterday I accidentally changed my phone's *(Samsung Galaxy Note 4 SM-N910C)* dpi from 640 to 140 using [Nomone Resolution changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomone.resolution_changer&hl=en)  that uses root and that **screwed** up my whole phone because now it completely skips my lock screen background and straight to my home background but all it shows me is the background itself and a *tiny* error that says "System UI has stopped" and its literally the only thing there. I tried resetting my dpi using adb commands but the problem is that my laptop isn't authorized to my phone, I mean usb debugging is on (i think) but I don't think that will help because I have no access whatsoever inside of my phone and I don't have CWM recovery flashed so I have no clue what to do :'((

I saw this [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/solved-soft-brick-phone-lcd-dpi-changes-t1694133/post45368439#post45368439) that says i should try installing a custom launcher to fix the problem but like I said its no use trying to do anything because my laptop isn't authorized:(

I seriously have no clue what to do and I really don't want to reset my phone because I have a lot of important files and pictures there, any suggestions? Thanks.

***Update***: So i managed to flash TWRP recovery but now i don't know what to do because I don't have a back up and i dont know the file that managed to change my dpi but at least i managed to progress somehow. What do i do next?

Comment: You can use ODIN to flash Twrp. https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote4qualcomm.html

Comment: That app which changed the dpi either did this by editing build.prop or setting a property (stored under /data/property), assuming it is not an Xposed module. You have to ascertain this and undo the change.

Comment: ill try flashing twrp but its gonna be difficult because i have a SM-N910C phone which is like the most difficult of note 4's

Comment: @Firelord do you have any idea how to "undo" the change?

Comment: Use the terminal in TWRP to issue the command to change the density.

Comment: You have to use grep and sed tool to make changes in build.prop if it was edited. Otherwise, if you can find one for your device on Internet use it to replace your modified one. Also, check /data/property to see if there is any file containing the term density somewhere? Delete it too. One of them is the cause of your problem.